# Bug: Calendar and Touchkit Theme

Tags: java, maven, mobile, calendar, vaadin

I have started to use Vaadin Touchkit recently. It looks very nice and fun but I have a problem.

I created touchkit app from the maven archetype like on website of vaadin.

I attached two screenshots

[image]

In one I am using annotation `@Theme("touchkit")` - which is ugly, in one - I am not using this annotation in file `MyProjectTouchKitUI.java`

I understood that I need to create a new WidgetSet and not optimize Calendar. I found the `CalendarConnector` class when I tried to watch how they are creating new widgetset in Parking Demo. I tried to play with this class but I am still cannot understand how it did this magic of changing calendar to this buggy thing.

Comment: Think you're missing your second screenshot. You can also override the Vaadin styles by creating your own theme. You can read more about that [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-creating.html). I wouldn't recommend completely removing the Vaadin theme, otherwise you will have formatting problems. Instead, extend and overwrite it

Comment: The thing is that for touchkit it is completely different story to create your own theme.

Comment: Sorry, minor confusion. The theme comes as a default of the widget set and there are details [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/touchkit/mobile-elements.html#mobile.elements.theme.css) for changing the themes